# show posts from 1 category only

Tags: wordpress

I have a `featured post` section at the top of my home page which shows the most recent post. The code for this is as follows:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

How can I change this to show posts from only 1 category?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the WordPress Codex?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Scroll, scroll, scroll, ah ehrm, a little bit scrolling down,.. Jackpot. It is: **category__in** or **cat** - Try it out:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 1337 /* YOUR CAT ID */ );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
```

Comment: It's not a standard Wordpress loop so I wasn't quite sure how to go about it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To retreive posts only from a certain category you could do like this:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category__in' => array(<Category_ID>) );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts ): $loop->the_post();
```

where `category__in` contains the ID of the category of interest.

You should also be able to use the `slug` for the category instead of the `ID`:

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'category_name' => <Category_SLUG> );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'cat'      => 22, // your cat ID
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);

// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<h2 class="postName">' . the_title() . '</h2>';
    echo '<p class="postText">' . the_excerpt() . '</p>';
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```